# Vue inside of blade - syntax

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, laravel-blade

How can I put `Vue`'s variables into the `Laravel`'s mustache brackets in following expression?

```
<a href="{{URL::route('frontend.article.show', ['slug' => '@{{article.slug}}', 'categoryId' =>'@{{ @article.id}}'])}}">"@{{article.title}}"></a>
```

This throws me an error like:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ')'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to access Vue variables (client side) inside of a PHP statement (server side). One way to solve this issue is to create the links inside Vue's `mounted()` method. How you can do this as follows:

First create the tags as follows

```
<a id="@{{ article.id }}" href="">@{{ article.title }}</a>
```

Then, you need to create the appropriate links inside Vue's `mounted()` method (or `created()`)

```
let path = "{{ route('frontend.article.show', ['slug' => 1, 'categoryId' => 2]) }}";
let url = path.replace(1, article.slug).replace(2, article.id);

// manipulate the DOM from here or pass it through to your data.
```

This is one way to approach it.